# What modifier is added to the Kinetic Blast's attack rolls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack-roll, kineticist, occult-magic

While reading up on the Kineticist, I noticed it never expressly says what modifier you add to attack rolls with your kinetic blast. So, what are all the modifiers you add to a kinetic blasts attack roll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Kinetic blasts are described as ranged attacks, and unless otherwise noted you add your Dexterity modifier to ranged attack rolls

From the [Kineticist page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist) :

> **Physical blasts are ranged attacks** that deal an amount of damage equal to 1d6+1 + the kineticist's Constitution modifier, increasing by
>   1d6+1 for every 2 kineticist levels beyond 1st. Spell resistance
>   doesn't apply against physical blasts. **Energy blasts are ranged
>   touch attacks** that deal an amount of damage equal to 1d6 + 1/2 the
>   kineticist's Constitution modifier, increasing by 1d6 for every 2
>   kineticist levels beyond 1st.

From [the general combat rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Bonus) :

> *Attack Bonus*
>
> Your attack bonus with a melee weapon is : Base attack bonus + Strength modifier + size modifier
>
> Your attack bonus with a **ranged weapon** is : Base attack bonus + **Dexterity modifier** + size modifier + range penalty

---

> *Touch Attacks*
>
> Some attacks completely disregard armor, including shields and natural
>   armor—the aggressor need only touch a foe for such an attack to take
>   full effect. In these cases, **the attacker makes a touch attack roll
>   (either ranged or melee)**.

So you just use your Dexterity modifier for attack rolls.

Comment: Don't forget you BAB, though